# Remove indentation to \texttt

Tags: indentation, typewriter

I'm writing my thesis using the `book` document class.
Each paragraph is indented automatically. This is fine with me for the whole thesis except in small pieces of "code" that are enclosed between `\texttt`.
I would like to eliminate the indentation in this case but I can't. I tried with `/noindent` but remains a small space (shorter than the indentation but a space). Then I tried it but has no effect because the indentation remains.

```
\texttt{
{\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
text 1: Follow the white rabbit!\\
text 2: Follow the tiny white rabbit!\\
}
}
```

How can I fix?
Thanks!

Comment: You wanna typeset code, do it properly (using package `listings  or `minted`). Alternatively, you want to typeset an algorithm. Several packages for algorithms available as well.

Comment: Do you maybe want something like the `verbatim` environment? This would be better although adding `\noindent` before `\texttt` would kill the indentation.

Comment: What you are doing right now, is starting a new paragraph and setting the parindent to zero, this is to late.

Comment: @Johannes_B I simply wish that these two lines are in black font as \texttt and no indentation.. What is the easiest way to do it? I used listings in another part of the thesis formatting code in a certain way which in this case would not fit...

Comment: Do it just like @cfr said in the comment above :-)

Comment: If you put `\noindent` before `\texttt`, you zero the indentation before the paragraph starts, so it has an effect. As @Johannes_B said, doing it after you start is too late.

Comment: You're missing two `%` characters at the end of the first two lines. Also remove the inner braces and the trailing ``\\``.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `\parindent` inside `\textt` is not something I'd do. Remember that an end-of-line is the same as a space:

```
\noindent\texttt{%
  text 1: Follow the white rabbit!\\
  text 2: Follow the tiny white rabbit!\\
}%
Some text follows.
```

But perhaps you want `verbatim`:

```
Some text before the typewriter type text
\begin{verbatim}
text 1: Follow the white rabbit!
text 2: Follow the tiny white rabbit!
\end{verbatim}
Some text follows.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` should precede the `\texttt{..}`, otherwise, it will not be effective. Further, you can as well use the `verbatim` environment (pointed out by egreg) or its `\verb|..|` command if it fulfills your needs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}%
\ttfamily
text 1: Follow the white rabbit!\par
text 2: Follow the tiny white rabbit!\par
}    
\bigskip
text 1: Follow the white rabbit! \\
text 2: Follow the tiny white rabbit! 

\end{document}
```

[image]